# Adding images to buttons in interface builder

Tags: ios, ios4, interface-builder, ios-4.2

I want to add an image to my button instead of text.  Can I do this in interface builder?  Any example I can look at?

Thanks
Deshawn

Comment: its literally the option below "title" on a UIButton in interface builder. its called "image", alternatively, there is the "backgroundImage" property that is right below these.

Comment: Sorry but I dont see a title option anywhere... I am using Xcode 4 and when I highlight my button, I dont see any option for title.

Answer (score 13):

1:select the button

2:select Attributes Inspector

3:change type to Custom

4:There are two ways to do this using the interface builder

-1: Make a button image->include it in your project->set the image as the "image" of the button.

-2: Make a button background image->include it in your project->set the image as the "background" of the button->set the "Title" of the button to anything you want.

Comment: you need to change type to custom after setting image as wierd things happen if you don't do so

Answer (score 4):

1. Add the image in your project.
2. In IB set the button type to custom.
3. Set the image in `Image` or `Background` box just below the `Title` box.

That's all.

Comment: Isn't there a drop down menu where rounded rect button is selected by default? Which SDK version you are using?

Comment: There are some major change in IB look-and-feel in SDK 4. Can you see the inspector for menu?

Answer (score 1):

I actually had to drag and drop the images folder into the *Project Navigator* and chose that the folder is a reference and only then, I could see the images in the *Media Library*.

From there the only thing you need to do is drag the picture where you want or change for the image name in the *Attribute inspector*.